# Increase the space size between specific images inside p tag in html

Tags: html, css

I am working on a site and I have provided a backend to the user for custom message. Everything which user type there will be displayed inside a p tag.

And I have also provided him with some specific codes which will be replaced with emoticons and other pics inside that p tag.

Now the problem is that, he doesn't want a space between every image, he only wants it where he has intentionally given it but as Browser will neglect more than one white space its a issue, bcoz single space isn't enough.

And I can't use margin, padding etc as it will work on every image inside that p tag,so I used css word-spacing property but which looks something like this

.msg p{word-spacing:15px;} where .msg is a container div but it gives me space in each word inside that p tag, but I only want space between images inside that p tag.

Thanks

Comment: an example snippet of the output HTML would work wonders for us. Also why not just replace two consecutive spaces with `&nbsp;&nbsp;`?

Comment: I will try to provide snippet, and I don't want to make it complicated for user, that's why I haven't said him to use &nbsp; for more spaces

Comment: Have you tried setting `margin` for the images inside the container with CSS?

Comment: No because it will increase the margin between each and every image, but I only want to increase space between images where user has intentionally provided a space

Answer (score 0):

Use Id Selector in the image then assign style for that.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp

Comment: Its a user choice how many images he wants to show in the post, and he can choose among hundreds of them. And its up to him, which two or three images he wants to show together and which he doesn't. So I can't use ID or class selector